# Python Pandas -- Concatenate strings if condition

Tags: python, pandas, concatenation

In a `pd.DataFrame` I have strings in column `A` whose `len` is equal to 5 or 6.  If the cell value `len(value) == 5` then I need to concatenate the string `'7'`  to the beginning of the cell value.  I am currently trying the code below, but cannot seem to use apply with the `inplace=True` argument.

```
 df[df['A'].str.len() == 5]['A'].apply(lambda x: '7' + str(x))
```

this will return the column - but won't modify the dataframe inplace...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try:

```
df['A'] = df.A.apply(lambda s: '7' + s if len(s) == 5 else s)
```